# Why is the session beans created as Singleton bean at starting and can it not by created by creating session?

Tags: spring

I am using for web application with spring 5, JSF 2.3, Primefaces, CDI, Hibernate.

Why is the spring-managed session bean created as Singleton bean at starting and why can it not be created by creating session?

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
// or import org.springframework.web.context.annotation.SessionScope;
// or import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("testSetting")
@Scope("session")
// or @SessionScope
// or @SessionScoped
public class TestSettingsBacking implements Serializable {
...
}
```

Comment: at 'starting' what? The application? And most of the time it will be created when it is needed somewhere. So please be more specific

Comment: At starting tomcat will that bean be created but it is not needed somewhere at the starting. If a user login in the application and call that bean, but it will be used without creating in session scope  using  **javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped** That is Singleton by default

Comment: Spring doesn't understand the javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped annotation at all. You can compare this with finding a post-it sticker on your fridge, but written in some ancient language you cannot read.
So it will simply ignore this annotation and fall back to the standard - Singletons!

Comment: Thanks. I dropped libs of CDI 2 and added only **javax.inject**. Also I am using scope only from spring lib. Now it is working. Tutorial is helpful for me: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/